# Unable to deserialize string to dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, deserialization

I am deserializing a string to Dictionary. Here is the code for deserialization:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string serialized)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new StringReader(serialized);
        using (XmlTextReader stm = new XmlTextReader(reader))
        {
            reader = null;
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stm);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am passing the input string :

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";
```

However I get an error at the line `ReadObject(stm)` :

> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].
>   Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

I have tried giving the input like this:

```
string json = "[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}]";
```

But I am still getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I cannot change the Deserialize method as its a method written by my client. I am just writing the unit test for testing it.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397733/deserializing-a-list-of-objects-that-contain-a-dictionary

Comment: what about string json = "['key1':'value1','key2':'value2']"; ?

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx.Specially https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908232(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library but are you sure XmlTextReader deserializes JSON?

Comment: Why are you creating an `XmlTextReader`? Moreso, you don't seem to be using it at all.

Comment: please take a look at the edit I made in the question

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to pass a JSON to your method? `DataContractSerializer` is used to serialize to XML, not JSON.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes the method has an input of type string. Should I pass the input string in the xml format? something like <key>Key1</key> ?

Comment: If it's using a `DataContractSerializer,` then you probably should. I would advise you to ask your client.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov OK thanks will do...Can u pls write an example as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of jumping through all these hoops and using `DataContractSerializer` and creating custom logic to parse json, I advise you to look into [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which makes this a joy:

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

**Edit:**

It looks as if you're trying to pass a JSON to a method that can only parse XML strings. I advise you ask your client provider what acceptable inputs can be used.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit I made to the question

Comment: @nitinvertigo Well, you could either use XML in the first place or else JSON.NET does support conversion:  http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";
var o = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
var mem = new MemoryStream(UTF32Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new StreamReader(json.ToCharArray()));
mem.Position = 0;
var o2 = o.ReadObject(mem);

public class T
{
    public string key1 { get; set; }
    public string key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: pls see the edit part of my question...I cannot change the deserialize method. I just wanted to know the correct format of input for the above deserialize method